# How do I find out the reason for Paint being called on every scroll event using chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, performance, scroll, google-chrome-devtools, reflow

[image: Devtools snapshot for scrolling webpage]

While trying to figure out why the page is janky, I checked on every scroll event there is a call to paint the whole page (a reflow I guess) but I couldn't figure out why this full page paint is happening, can devtools provide more information

Answer (score 0):

In the **Sources** panel you can set breakpoints on `scroll` events. Would that help?

[image]